# How to prevent buttons overflowing downward?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow, css-position

I have a div that contains some buttons. The div has an overflow so that the buttons are still usable when the screen is resized however it is not overflowing in the way that I hoped.

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}
button {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>BUTT 01</button>
  <button>BUTT 02</button>
  <button>BUTT 03</button>
  <button>BUTT 04</button>
  <button>BUTT 05</button>
  <button>BUTT 06</button>
</div>
```

When the div is small enough to trigger the overflow it moves the last buttons downward and then the overflow is down.

Is it possible to have the images stay horizontal to each other and overflow along the x axis?

I have a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ntxcxkhx/ to illustrate the issue that I am having

Comment: Are you wanting them to stay in a straight line no matter the size of the screen? side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `white-space: nowrap;` on the container.

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
button {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>BUTT 01</button>
  <button>BUTT 02</button>
  <button>BUTT 03</button>
  <button>BUTT 04</button>
  <button>BUTT 05</button>
  <button>BUTT 06</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!!. Simple yet easy solution!

Comment: This was a fantastic answer, one line solutions are always great, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:flex` and `overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden` to div

Here is the JSfiddle [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ntxcxkhx/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you set a dynamic width on the parent div, the container will resize relative to the window width, forcing the buttons onto a new line.

Using `overflow-x: scroll` and `white-space: nowrap`, you should get the behavior you're looking for.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntxcxkhx/27/